# Is there a .into_sub_account_truncating equivalent for Javascript?

Tags: polkadot-js, api, javascript

In rust I use:

`.into_sub_account_truncating()`

Is there a Javascript equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this code snippet](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-js-utilities/blob/6062b9b5c69e6c384a773c9fac940fd461a8b845/utilities.js#L279-L305) to derive a sub account. You can test it out at [this page](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/).

Comment: Its not quite that, though regarding formulating accounts from a concatenation of addresses, this code snippet in the same page is more relevant hexToAccount https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-js-utilities/blob/6062b9b5c69e6c384a773c9fac940fd461a8b845/utilities.js#L76. 

What i wanted to check if there was already a method i could use which would add zeroes and truncating them so it fits the correct length, before embarking on doing it manually. for now appending a fixed length of zeroes works for me.